# Integrando o Delphi ao Word (habilitando o botão de Salvar do Word)

Tags: delphi, microsoft-word, delphi-tokyo

Há algum tempo criei um sistema que integro o ***MS Word*** com o ***Delphi***, só que o botão de *Salvar* do Word fica desabilitado.

[image: botão de Salvar desabilitado]

Seria importante que esse botão ficasse habilitado, pois ele já salva no lugar onde o arquivo foi criado.
Vou por o código de como eu abro o documento.

```
procedure TfrmConsultas.btnCaregarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  OleContainer: TOleContainer;
begin
  try
    with OleContainer do
    begin
      if OleObjectInterface <> Nil then
      begin
        DestroyObject;
      end;
      //Nome do arquivo usado para abrir o arquivo de entrvista de Consulta
      vNomeArquivo  := 'Nome do Arquivo';
      // Cria o Arquivo a partir do conteúdo de um arquivo de modelo.
      try
        // Código que deve ser tratado caso haja uma exceção
        OleContainer.CreateObjectFromFile(vNomeArquivo, False);
        OleContainer.DoVerb(ovPrimary);
        OleContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);
        OleContainer.DoVerb(ovUIActivate);
        OleContainer.DoVerb(ovInPlaceActivate);
        Perform(WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, MK_LBUTTON, 0);

        if (DM.tbConsultas.State in [dsInsert]) or
           ((DM.tbConsultasMODELO_ARQUIVO.AsString <> '') and
            (cbbModelos.Text <> '')) or ((cbbModelos.Text <> '') and
            (DM.tbConsultasMODELO_ARQUIVO.AsString = '')) then
          FindAndReplace;
      except
        //  Fechar o arquivo
        DestroyObject;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;

end;
```

Depois de modificar o conteúdo eu Salvo.

```
OleContainer.OleObject.SaveAs (FileName, wdFormatDocument, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, False);
```

- Quero saber se tem como habilitar esse botão

Comment: Já tentou verificar se consegue lá em personalização de barra de ferramentas?

Comment: Você pode salvara com o comando `WordDocument1.SaveAs(docdestino);` coloca no botão de saida ai o usuário já sai salvando.

Comment: tentou na inicialização do programa já direcionar esse botão como enabled? Não conheço seu sistema mais no Form.create coloque todas as propriedades que desejar de forma padrão habilitado ou não. Acho que é somente isso um abraço sucesso.

Comment: @user113557 o botão da imagem que está na pergunta não foi criado por mim ele **é do word** eu não tenho como habilita-lo colocando `botao.doWord.enable := True` se você reparar na imagem ele é do sistema.

Comment: ali é um `TOleContainer` que eu trago a tela do word.

Answer (score -1):

Normalmente, o botão salvar só fica habilitado após alguma alteração no documento ser realizada pelo próprio Word (sem automation). Para que o Word entenda que o documento pode ser salvo, use a propriedade Saved, como no exemplo:

`var
  Word, Doc: OleVariant;
begin
  Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  Doc := Word.Documents.Add;
  ... //outros comandos
  Doc.Saved := False;
end;`

Comment: Opa! Vou testar só que não posso testar agora muito, obrigado!

Comment: Não Conseguir fazer funcionar!

Comment: Coloque as partes relevantes do seu código pra gente tentar entender o que está faltando.